# Can I add a custom condition around a ScrollView attribute in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to add a condition in my React Native scroll view attribute. This is my code:

```
<ScrollView ref={(ref) => this._refScrollView = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={this.scrollToEnd} refreshControl={
        if(pullToRefresh == 'conversations'){
        <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
        }
    }>
```

Although is is giving me an error, I just want to ask if is there any possible way to only have `RefreshControl` section only if `PullToRefresh == 'conversations'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally put `refreshControl`, try following

```
<ScrollView 
    ref={(ref) => this._refScrollView = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={this.scrollToEnd}
    refreshControl={
        (pullToRefresh == 'conversations') &&
        <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
    }
>
...
</ScrollView>
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what error you get but I think it might be a syntax error. Change the code as below

```
<ScrollView 
  ref={(ref) => this._refScrollView = ref}
  onContentSizeChange={this.scrollToEnd} 
  refreshControl={
    (pullToRefresh == 'conversations') && {
      <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
      />
    }
  }
>
```